# phoenix elixir exaws use with minio(upload file)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, minio

I'm trying to use [ExAws](https://github.com/CargoSense/ex_aws) library along with [minio](https://minio.io/).
I try to upload the file:

```
filepath
|> S3.Upload.stream_file
|> S3.upload(bucket_name, path)
|> ExAws.request!
```

and I get an error:

```
[error] #PID<0.1041.0> running Myapp.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: POST /resources/upload
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: %{body: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<InitiateMultipartUploadResult xmlns=\"http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/\"><Bucket>user-1</Bucket><Key>docs/tsetup.0.9.51.tar.xz</Key><UploadId>35e9c8b0-ac34-4411-b39b-790a0104df93</UploadId></InitiateMultipartUploadResult>", headers: [{"Accept-Ranges", "bytes"}, {"Server", "Minio/DEVELOPMENT.GOGET (linux; amd64)"}, {"Vary", "Origin"}, {"X-Amz-Request-Id", "K4O7RNNSRLAMSL26"}, {"Date", "Tue, 11 Oct 2016 20:53:58 GMT"}, {"Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"}, {"Transfer-Encoding", "chunked"}], status_code: 200}
        (ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/s3/upload.ex:39: ExAws.S3.Upload.initialize!/2
        (ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/s3/upload.ex:80: ExAws.Operation.ExAws.S3.Upload.perform/2
        (ex_aws) lib/ex_aws.ex:41: ExAws.request!/2
        (Myapp) web/models/resource.ex:68: Myapp.Resource.put_file_to_cloud/1
        (Myapp) web/controllers/resource_controller.ex:59: Myapp.ResourceController.upload/2
        (Myapp) web/controllers/resource_controller.ex:1: Myapp.ResourceController.action/2
        (Myapp) web/controllers/resource_controller.ex:1: Myapp.ResourceController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
        (Myapp) lib/Myapp/endpoint.ex:1: Myapp.Endpoint.instrument/4
        (Myapp) lib/phoenix/router.ex:261: Myapp.Router.dispatch/2
        (Myapp) web/router.ex:1: Myapp.Router.do_call/2
        (Myapp) lib/Myapp/endpoint.ex:1: Myapp.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
        (Myapp) lib/plug/debugger.ex:123: Myapp.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
        (Myapp) lib/Myapp/endpoint.ex:1: Myapp.Endpoint.call/2
        (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
        (cowboy) src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

I see by the response that the file upload begins. This mini returns the answer is not as expected exaws? or the problem is in something else?

Upd: after adding sweet_xml now get another error:

```
[error] GenServer #PID<0.593.0> terminating
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: nil
    (ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/s3/upload.ex:69: ExAws.S3.Upload.upload_chunk!/3
    lib/flow/materialize.ex:493: anonymous fn/4 in Experimental.Flow.Materialize.mapper/2
    lib/flow/materialize.ex:462: Experimental.Flow.Materialize."-mapper_ops/1-lists^foldl/2-1-"/3
    lib/flow/materialize.ex:462: anonymous fn/5 in Experimental.Flow.Materialize.mapper_ops/1
    lib/flow/map_reducer.ex:57: Experimental.Flow.MapReducer.handle_events/3
    lib/gen_stage.ex:2190: Experimental.GenStage.consumer_dispatch/7
    lib/gen_stage.ex:2313: Experimental.GenStage.take_pc_events/3
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:601: :gen_server.try_dispatch/4
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:667: :gen_server.handle_msg/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: {:"$gen_consumer", {#PID<0.592.0>, #Reference<0.0.2.533>}, [{<<255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 72, 0, 72, 0, 0, 255, 219, 0, 67, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, ...>>, 1}]}
State: {%{#Reference<0.0.2.533> => nil}, %{consumers: [{#Reference<0.0.2.544>, #Reference<0.0.2.546>}], done: [#Reference<0.0.2.533>], done?: false, trigger: #Function<2.69990182/4 in Experimental.Flow.Window.Global.materialize/4>}, {0, 4}, [], #Function<29.77971684/4 in Experimental.Flow.Materialize.mapper_ops/1>}
[error] Ranch protocol #PID<0.587.0> (:cowboy_protocol) of listener Myapp.Endpoint.HTTP terminated
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: nil
        (ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/s3/upload.ex:69: ExAws.S3.Upload.upload_chunk!/3
        lib/flow/materialize.ex:493: anonymous fn/4 in Experimental.Flow.Materialize.mapper/2
        lib/flow/materialize.ex:462: Experimental.Flow.Materialize."-mapper_ops/1-lists^foldl/2-1-"/3
        lib/flow/materialize.ex:462: anonymous fn/5 in Experimental.Flow.Materialize.mapper_ops/1
        lib/flow/map_reducer.ex:57: Experimental.Flow.MapReducer.handle_events/3
        lib/gen_stage.ex:2190: Experimental.GenStage.consumer_dispatch/7
        lib/gen_stage.ex:2313: Experimental.GenStage.take_pc_events/3
        (stdlib) gen_server.erl:601: :gen_server.try_dispatch/4
        (stdlib) gen_server.erl:667: :gen_server.handle_msg/5
        (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

at the same time, I see that the download is in wireshark [image: trace], but in the storage folder is empty

I looked more at the response from Minio, and I see that there is etag:

`Frame 1138: 344 bytes on wire (2752 bits), 344 bytes captured (2752 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: 00:00:00_00:00:00 (00:00:00:00:00:00), Dst: 00:00:00_00:00:00 (00:00:00:00:00:00)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 9000 (9000), Dst Port: 42324 (42324), Seq: 515, Ack: 1539815, Len: 278
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
    Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n
    Etag: "2501de281894f7a1f79e8e0d6b8e7d85"\r\n
    Server: Minio/DEVELOPMENT.GOGET (linux; amd64)\r\n
    Vary: Origin\r\n
    X-Amz-Request-Id: M81ULLKCXKH0KRXD\r\n
    Date: Fri, 14 Oct 2016 15:00:16 GMT\r\n
    Content-Length: 0\r\n
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n
    \r\n
    [HTTP response 2/2]
    [Time since request: 0.008850143 seconds]
    [Prev request in frame: 1016]
    [Prev response in frame: 1028]
    [Request in frame: 1032]`

UPD: the problem is solved by the author of the ExAws library - https://github.com/CargoSense/ex_aws/issues/253

Comment: what configuration did you do to use Minio as cloud storage in you elixir application? I am not able to find the config for endpoint.
`config :ex_aws,   debug_requests: true,  region: "eu-central-1"`

Comment: Never-mind. I got the configuration option:
`s3: [ scheme: "http://", host: "localhost", region: "eu-west-1", port: 9000]`

Answer (score 2):

ExAWS upload is expecting a response of **%{body: %{upload_id: upload_id}}**, but you are getting unparsed XML as body. S3 require XML codec, so make sure you have XML parsing library **sweet_xml** added to your deps.

HIH

Comment: Thank you! after adding sweet_xml I  get another error. I add it to the question

Comment: Uploading in chunks to AWS returns with ETag with each chunk request and library code is expecting that 'etag' in response, as it couldn't find that info in response from AWS, so match is failing. Please review the detailed HTTP response from AWS for each chunk upload and see if that contains the ETag field. 

ETag response from AWS is necessary to complete the multipart upload.

Comment: etag is present in the response from the minio

Comment: Seems like this issue is fixed via https://github.com/CargoSense/ex_aws/issues/253. @Marsel.V can you test and if it works as intended?

Comment: @koolhead17Yes, I immediately added a response in which I indicated that the problem had been resolved. But my answer was deleted